# Strange blue screen issue after Dell BIOS update

Tags: windows, bsod

After Dell Windows 10 A25 BIOS update, my computer will start and shutdown with no problem but if I use "restart" function, I get blue screen error "inaccessible boot device". I reinstalled BIOS again thinking it might be corrupt, but same problem. ON/OFF = NO PROBLEM, RESTART = PROBLEM. I know eventually I will have to restart the machine so I need to see if I can figure out what the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the BIOS back up again properly, or are you just running at [what may be totally different from before] defaults?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to BIOS after install. It was working fine until I tried to use restart and then noticed problem. But it still works fine if I just use start and shutdown. Not sure what BIOS setting would make this happen.

Comment: Did you write down the pervious settings? Did you restore them? Defaults are fine for a raw motherboard, not necessarily your machine. The difference can mean... well.. you're seeing it now:/  Updating the BIOS is one of those things you really only ever should do if the motherboard manufacturer says it solves an issue you were having. If not, just leave them well alone.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tetsujin. Unfortunately, I did not write down settings before update. Dell recommended the update so I did it. I have gone through BIOS settings and they seem to be correct. Seems like incorrect setting would effect both startup and restart and not just restart.

Comment: Windows uses Fast Startup, if enabled, which keeps an image of the kernel on disk -- this may be why Shutdown (hybrid) is still working, but restart does not (see https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html). This implies that, if *hyberfil.sys* is damaged, you may not be able to boot at all. First, image your HDD before trying to fix this issue, so you can get back to the current state. Then try tuning off Fast Startup and Hibernate and try rebooting.

Comment: Fast startup and hibernate are off. I had trouble with them in the past and disabled them and they are still off. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and effort to help me. After analyzing the issue over and over, I suddenly remembered that when I downloaded the BIOS from Dell that a couple of Intel items were downloaded also. So I deleted Intel Management & Security and Intel Rapid Storage Technology and that cleared up the blue screen issue. Have a great day.